# Angular ui-router params if specific child-url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to define $stateParams-values when a specific state is hit.
I have a parent-state with 2 childs that are all using the same view:

```
.state('customer {
    url: '/customer',
    templateUrl: '/customer/overview/customer.overview.html',
    resolve: customerResolve,
    controller: 'customer.overview.controller',
    params: { type: null }
})

.state('customer.a' {
    url: '/a',
    templateUrl: '/customer/overview/customer.overview.html',
    resolve: customerResolve,
    controller: 'customer.overview.controller',
    params: { type: 'a' }
})

.state('customer.b' {
    url: '/b',
    templateUrl: '/customer/overview/customer.overview.html',
    resolve: customerResolve,
    controller: 'customer.overview.controller',
    params: { type: 'b'}
})
```

They all have the same resolve:

```
var customerResolve = {

    resolvedCustomers: ['$state', '$stateParams', function ($state, $stateParams) {

        if ($stateParams.type == "a")
        {
            //resolve data
        }
        else if ($stateParams.status == "b") {

            //resolve data
        }
    }]
}
```

When I navigate to **.../customer/a** I do reach my resolve but I expect the `$stateParams.type` to be `a` but it is `null`. The same for **.../customer/b**.

The value is `null` because the parent-state is defined that way. I can't delete the parent-params because that will delete my type-parameter completely in the resolve. I just want to define the type-parameter in my parent-state but not apply a value like 'null' or something else, I want my child-states to fill that type-parameter.

I can achieve it using ui-sref like so: `<a ui-sref="customer({type: 'a'})">Customer type A</a>`

But I want to set the type-parameter by just navigating to the url. If more clarity is need I can provide a plunkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you shouldn't have to have a configuration like yours where your parent and all children have same `templates` and `controllers`. But if you really need what you mentioned, you can use the `data` property available in state configuration as explained [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects) and access it using `$state.current.data`

I have created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BUhTeGXlGmLOb0kxuq4D?p=preview) using same to demonstrate your use case

Comment: This indeed does the job and is what I needed. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done it recently

```
myApp.config( function($routeProvider) {
      when('/user/:userID', {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/user.html',
        controller: 'userPageCtrl'
      })
  });
```

Then in your controller

```
myApp.controller('userPageCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams',
function($scope, $routeParams) {

    console.log("user controller");
    console.log("route param", $routeParams);
});
```

and `$routeParams` will have userID, and the urls are accessed by `/user/2`, `/user/3`, etc

edit: I presume this is done similarly, ie with the `:param` syntax, in angular ui

Comment: Not quite what im looking for. I don't have id-parameters on this page as it is an overview of multiple customers of a specific type. I am using the same page and controller for two types of customer.

Comment: In your controller, can't you just use and if statement based on the param? Userid could just as easily be a usertype param. My understanding was that you needed the `:routeParameter` syntax, which I assume is the same.